# 2d array printing values

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

So i am making a 2d array for a library system task. This is what my array looks like
`books = [[0, "From Lukov with Love", True],[1, "172 hours on the moon",True],[2, "Archer's Voice",False],[3, "Floored",True],[4, "The Mermaid of Black Conch"],[5, "Kite Runner",True],[6, "The Brilliant World of Tom Gates", False], [7,"1984", False]]`

I am doing a function called addBook where if a book is not already in the library i can add a book to the array. I used append to add a book but i want to print the updated array, im not too sure how to do that any advice?
`

```
def addBook(books):
  newBook = input("what book would you like to add to the library?")
  newAuthor = input("who is wrote this book? ") #im not sure i need this
  
  found = False
  for i in range(len(books)):
    if books[i][1] == newBook:
      found = True
  if found == False:
    books.append(newBook)
    print(books) #how do i print all the book titles
  else:
    print("this book is already in the library")
```

`

I thought if i did print(books[i][1]) it would print all the book titles

Comment: Where is `i` coming from in `print(books[i][1])`

Comment: Each element in the array seems to be pretty specific. Maybe you could make those data classes instead (just a thought). You could have `books` consist of objects of type `Book`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug. You expect each object in books[][] to be in format:
`[index, title, bool]`, however when you add a new book you do:
`books.append(newBook)` where newBook is only a title of the book.
Next time you will iterate over the list and try to access books[i][1] you will get a runtime error.

Maintaining this database in a list is probably not a good idea. To check if a book exists you need to go over the entire database in O(N) time, and removing and adding a book will be a pain.
Look into dictionary, and maybe creating a Book object, so you know exactly what each element in books is. It will be much easier for you to add functionality later to the database.